# ion-textarea inside ion-item not working on IONIC 2

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ion-textarea inside of ion-item. It's shows fine, but when I press over the textarea, it's shows and hides the keyboard. And because the keyboard is hidden, I cannot put any text.

It's like that onblur event was triggered inmediatly after that I touched screen.

This is my code:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Comment</ion-label>
    <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="formData.comment" name="comment" placeholder="Put any comment..."></ion-textarea>
</ion-item>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think something wrong with you device. restart you device or run on another device.

Comment: did you solved this issue? I've multiple ion-textarea on same page first one is working fine. For rest double ion-textarea tags are there in DOM and clicking on them hides the keyboard. I applied the answer given by celeb swank then the textarea hides behind the keyboard.

Comment: I remember that I resolve it using divs instead ion-item, but I don't have access anymore to source code to provide it... sorry =7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will often run into errors like this whenever using ion-item in that manner. I had the same thing happen with inputs until I just wrapped them in a div instead.

[Per the docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/item/Item/) - *An item can contain text, images, and anything else. Generally it is placed in a list with other items. It can easily be swiped, deleted, reordered, edited, and more. **An item is only required to be in a List if manipulating the item via gestures is required.** It requires an ItemSliding wrapper element in order to be swiped.*

You may want to restructure your code or format that ion-item in a list of some sort.